# GoogleカレンダーAPIで"error": "invalid_grant"が出力されるのを解決したいです。

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

GoogleカレンダーAPIを利用したく、テスト実行していたのですが、下記エラーが出力されます。

##### エラーメッセージ

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Google\Service\Exception: {
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "Token has been expired or revoked."
}
```

#### 行った操作の手順

- 一度読み込みのみでの認証を通過。
- 書き込みも行いたくコードを変更して再度トライ。
- エラーが出力されサードパーティ認証解除とTrashTokenの削除を実行。
- 通過できていた処理をもう１度実行したところ、そちらも不可になる。

エラーの解決方法も、元の状態への戻し方もわからず困っています。
どなたかご存知の方いたら、教えていただけたら助かります。
よろしくお願いします。

##### 現状のコード

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
define('CLIENT_PATH', __DIR__ . '/client.json');
if (php_sapi_name() != 'cli') {
    throw new Exception('This application must be run on the command line.');
}

/**
 * Returns an authorized API client.
 * @return Google_Client the authorized client object
 */
    function getClient()
{
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('Google Calendar API PHP Quickstart');
    $client->setScopes(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR_EVENTS);
    $client->setAuthConfig(CLIENT_PATH);
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $client->setPrompt('select_account consent');

    // Load previously authorized token from a file, if it exists.
    // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    // created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    // time.
    $tokenPath = 'token.json';
    if (file_exists($tokenPath)) {
        $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($tokenPath), true);
        $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
    }

    // If there is no previous token or it's expired.
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        // Refresh the token if possible, else fetch a new one.
        if ($client->getRefreshToken()) {
            $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
        } else {
            // Request authorization from the user.
            $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
            printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
            print 'Enter verification code: ';
            $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

            // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
            $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
            $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

            // Check to see if there was an error.
            if (array_key_exists('error', $accessToken)) {
                throw new Exception(join(', ', $accessToken));
            }
        }
        // Save the token to a file.
        if (!file_exists(dirname($tokenPath))) {
            mkdir(dirname($tokenPath), 0700, true);
        }
        file_put_contents($tokenPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
    }
    return $client;
}

// Get the API client and construct the service object.
$client = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

// Print the next 10 events on the user's calendar.
$calendarId = 'primary';
$optParams = array(
    'maxResults' => 15,
    'orderBy' => 'startTime',
    'singleEvents' => true,
    'timeMin' => date('c'),
);
$results = $service->events->listEvents($calendarId, $optParams);
$events = $results->getItems();

if (empty($events)) {
    print "No upcoming events found.\n";
} else {
    print "Upcoming events:\n";
    foreach ($events as $event) {
        $start = $event->start->dateTime;
        if (empty($start)) {
            $start = $event->start->date;
        }
        printf("%s (%s)\n", $event->getSummary(), $start);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

発行されていたtoken.jsonを削除したら、元に戻りエラー解決できました！